# Issue finding libproj.so.25

Tags: python, cartopy

I am trying to use cartopy in a python project, using:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io.img_tiles import OSM
```

However, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 27, in <module>
    import cartopy.trace
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 27, in <module>
    import cartopy.trace
ImportError: libproj.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`libproj.so.25` is installed at `/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu`

Any ideas on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this following this issue: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1966#issuecomment-994470292

Just do it: sudo ldconfig